# How to validate when enter date in TextBox in asp.net using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This is my code

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="datetime.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[id$=txtDate]").datepicker({});
            $("#txtDate").blur(function () {
                val = $(this).val();
                val1 = Date.parse(val);

                if (isNaN(val1) == true && val !== '') {
                    alert('Date is not valid');
                    $("#txtDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate("mm-dd-yy", new Date()));
                }
                else {
                    console.log(val1);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code i have a textbox when user click on textbox it opens datepicker and select date. if user enter date manually how to validate using jquery.
Eg:- 01011       -->  this time shows alert for invalid date
Eg:- 01-01-2016

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to change to `type="date"` which is specially provided for entering dates.

Comment: By the way, using this type of input warrants that the entered value is always legal.

Answer (score 1):

Try validating the date using regex,this below expression will accept all the possible 3 formats `dd/mm/yyyy`,`dd-mm-yyyy` or `dd.mm.yyyy`.

Jquery:

```
$("#txtDate").datepicker();
$("#txtDate").blur(function () {

var pattern = /^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$/;

var validateDate = pattern.test($(this).val());

if(validateDate)
{
 alert('Date is valid');
}
else
{
alert('Date is not valid');
}
)};
```

Comment: Your logic working fine but when i click on textbox it open calender i select date it shows date is not valid then next second time select date it working fine

Comment: Can you edit your code snippet by giving absolute urls for jquery library and ui js because its causing issue while running the snippet.

Comment: Now check once again in my code i change the jquery urls

Comment: If you just want the user either enter date manually or choose from the datepicker means try changing the date format of the date picker like this $("#txtDate").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"});..

Comment: And Stop using the blur function if you want to trigger something during the onselect of data picker means use like this  $("#txtDate").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",onSelect: function (dateText) { alert('Date') }});

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code for datetime in asp.net using jquery

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="datetime.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
   <link type="text/css" href="Content/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <%--  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />--%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#txtDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
            //Bind keyup/keydown to the input
            $("#txtDate").bind('keyup', 'keydown', function (e) {

                //To accomdate for backspacing, we detect which key was pressed - if backspace, do nothing:
                if (e.which !== 8) {

                    var length = $("#txtDate").val().length;
                    if (length == 2) {
                        if ($("#txtDate").val().charAt($("#txtDate").val().length - 1) == '/') {
                            $("#txtDate").val("0" + $("#txtDate").val().substring(0, 1));
                        }
                        var date = $("#txtDate").val().substring(0, 2);
                        if (date > 31) {
                            $("#txtDate").val("");
                        }
                    }

                    else
                        if (length == 5) {
                            if ($("#txtDate").val().charAt($("#txtDate").val().length - 1) == '/') {
                                $("#txtDate").val($("#txtDate").val().substring(0,3)+ "0" + $("#txtDate").val().substring(3, 4));
                            }
                            var month = $("#txtDate").val().substring(3, 5);
                            if (month > 12) {
                                $("#txtDate").val($("#txtDate").val().substring(0, 2));
                            }
                        }
                    if (length > 6) {
                        if ($("#txtDate").val().charAt($("#txtDate").val().length - 1) == '/') {
                            $("#txtDate").val($("#txtDate").val().substring(0, length-1));
                        }
                    }
                        
                            var numChars = $("#txtDate").val().length;

                            if (numChars === 2 || numChars === 5) {
                                var thisVal = $("#txtDate").val();
                                thisVal += '/';
                                $("#txtDate").val(thisVal);
                            }
                  
                }
            });
            $("#txtDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", new Date()));
            $("#txtDate").blur(function () {
                
                val = $(this).val();
                val1 = Date.parse(val);
                if (isNaN(val1) == true && val !== '') {
                    alert('Date is not valid');
                    $("#txtDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", new Date()));
                }
                else {
                    console.log(val1);
                }
            });
      
        });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" MaxLength="10" type="date"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```